# Numpy Bincount() with combined float and int arrays

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, statistics

I'm trying to write a program to gather statistical data from stock trades. I've got an array of prices and a corresponding array with the number of trades at each price. I asked a question earlier and got some good answers to get me on the right path. Now I'm finding new problems.

The arrays look something like this:

```
price = [229.0, 229.3, 229.0, 229.1, 228.9, 229.0, 229.1]
tradesize = [400, 800, 450, 65, 2, 600, 150]
```

I've tried to use a variety of methods to get the mode and median with minimal success. I kept running into roadblocks with pandas and changed to a numpy array. At first, I tried to get the sum of the individual price points by using price as an index in dataframes and getting the sum of the other column with:

```
newarray = groupby['price'].sum()
```

This gave me a nice array that looked something like this:

```
228.9, 2
229.0, 1450
229.1, 215
229.3, 800
```

This worked nicely but I kept running into issues extracting the price column.

My next idea was to use `np.bincount()` to count the number of trades at each price point. I'm running into issues with `TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'`. When I change the price to an integer it works nicely, but the rounding error makes the code essentially useless.

I'm not sure I can get the data I need without summing the number of sales at each price point. For example, I looked into `np.argmax()` but quickly realized that this only gave the first highest size of trade, and really failed if combined trades added to a higher value, such as the 229.3 and 229.0 points in my example above.

I'm not married to any particular method, as I extract the data from a CSV file as a pandas dataframe, get a variety of information from that, convert it to a pandas array, and finally get a variety of information from the new array. Each method seems to offer a little functionality that is better suited to one data point than the other. If it helps, I'm dealing with tens of thousands of data points so memory utilization and speed are a concern.

I appreciate any help and thank everyone in advance!

Comment: FYI: `bincount` is designed for integer arrays, and is really only practical for arrays of relatively small integers.

Comment: As is usual, as soon as I ask a question, I think I find an answer. I set the price column as the index in dataframe and ran:            ```new = self.df.groupby(['price']).sum()
 mode= new['tradesize'].idxmax()``` and appear to have an answer. .I don't think it will be overly difficult to loop this and make sure there aren't any other max value hiding after this hits the first one in the column